# How to suppress rsyslogd HUPed messages from logcheck?

Tags: debian, rsyslog, logcheck

Getting these...

```
Jan  7 06:25:01 debian liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="551" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
```

Debian default logcheck rule /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/rsyslog

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ rsyslogd: \[origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="[0-9.]+" x-pid="[0-9]+" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"\] rsyslogd was HUPed$
```

Custom rules tried /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/rsyslog-fix

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ liblogging-stdlog:  \[origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="[0-9.]+" x-pid="[0-9]+" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"\] rsyslogd was HUPed$
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ liblogging-stdlog:  \[origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="[0-9.]+" x-pid="[[:digit:]]+" x-info="http:\/\/www\.rsyslog\.com"\] rsyslogd was HUPed$
```

Any idea?? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check for whitespace or special characters (like CR) at the end of the log line; try including them by temporarily closing your pattern with `.*$`.
2. Check `/etc/logcheck/violations.d` and `/etc/logcheck/cracking.d` for matching patterns, those directories have priority over `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d`.

`egrep -f /etc/logcheck/DIR/FILE` is a good tool to use for testing your rules.

Comment: Thanks the first command above seems to work, there was a missing space in my existing config...

Tested using egrep as you suggested. Tried logcheck-test it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

I simply added this line to /etc/rsyslog.conf and restarted it:

```
if ($msg contains "rsyslogd was HUPed") then stop
```

Good enough for me.